# How can I pass a 2d array to an asp.net MVC method from jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: actionURL,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { values: data },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

My controller method:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SaveParameter(string [][] values)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I have tried a bunch of things, but nothing is working. How can I compose 'data' in javascript??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to post data in next format

```
{
"values[0][0]": "Some value",
"values[1][0]": "Some value",
"values[0][1]": "Some value",
"values[1][1]": "Some value",
"values[2][0]": "Some value",
"values[0][2]": "Some value",
"values[2][1]": "Some value",
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSON.stringify.

```
var chiavi = [];
chiavi[0] = ["A", "B"];
chiavi[1] = ["C", "D"];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jsonUrl, 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Values: chiavi
            }),
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: @SLC: mmm can you see the request using Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug ? maybe the problem is on MVC side (modelbinding). Be sure to keep the traditional: true in your ajax call or default modelbinding won't work (assuming you're workign with MVC3)